# Scapy3: srp1 not capturing response packet when IP(dst='255.255.255.255')

Tags: python-3.5, scapy

How do I tell scapy to associate the response packet to the send packet when the using a broadcast for the IP(dst)?  I see the proper response packets with sniff, I just can't get srp/srp1 to grab them.

```
p = Ether(dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff')/IP(src='1.1.1.1', dst='255.255.255.255')/UDP(sport=53222, dport=2010)/Raw(load=b'{"stuff"}')
ans = srp1(p,iface='Bond1')

Packet sent:

###[ Ethernet ]### dst= ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff src= 11:11:11:11:11:11 type= 0x800
###[ IP ]### version= 4 ihl= 5 tos= 0x0 len= 76 id= 1 flags= frag= 0 ttl= 64 proto= udp chksum= 0xd81e src= 1.1.1.1 dst= 255.255.255.255 \options
###[ UDP ]### sport= 53222 dport= 2010 len= 56 chksum= 0x8e04
###[ Raw ]### load= '{"stuff"}'

Packet response:

###[ Ethernet ]### dst= 11:11:11:11:11:11 src= 22:22:22:22:22:22 type= 0x800
###[ IP ]### version= 4 ihl= 5 tos= 0x0 len= 207 id= 0 flags= DF frag= 0 ttl= 64 proto= udp chksum= 0xf507 src= 2.2.2.2 dst= 1.1.1.1 \options
###[ UDP ]### sport= 2010 dport= 53222 len= 187 chksum= 0xc61e
###[ Raw ]### load= '{"stuff response"}'
```

Scapy will only capture the response if the destination IP address is for the responding packet, however in my case I need to broadcast to find the destination.

Thanks!